# css difference between windows/Slackware/Ubuntu

Tags: css, windows, ubuntu, cross-browser, slackware

I have a site created with Joomla and some Components and I have customized the style.
In windows, all works great for all the browsers I tested (including IE), same for Linux Slackware while on Linux Ubuntu I have a problem. In fact the last component of the main menu goes to a new line both on chrome and firefox.

You can try it on: http://www.eliteboatcar.com/
The problem is on the last component #menu div (it is the button "Contatti").

Thanks

Comment: Almost certain to be a difference in the fonts rather than the CSS.

Comment: Well, probably you're right in fact I read that Ubuntu fonts are bigger than in other distributions and other operating systems.
How can I solve this problem then?
I thought to indentify the operating system and use a different CSS, is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm looking at the site now in Windows and Mint, and I really can't see that much difference. Do you have the Arial font installed on your Ubuntui machine? If yes, are you sure your zoom factor and/or DPI is the same as on the Windows machine? If no, what font is substituted for Arial?